install specific version of github action runner controller in ubuntu 20.04
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/managing-self-hosted-runners-with-actions-runner-controller/quickstart-for-actions-runner-controller
I'm trying to install the latest version of GitHub Action Runners. I could do it on Ubuntu 22.04 but I can't find a way to do it on 20.04 which is a client requirement. I tried to build them from the official website: https://github.com/actions/actions-runner-controller/blob/master/runner/actions-runner.ubuntu-20.04.dockerfile , they build but then they don't work. Any ideas?
